# save blob file to server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to saeve recorded file to the server.
For recording purpose I am using demos [recorder](https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder)

At the end of recording it gives me a blob-link to the recorded file. 
So After googling a bit I found that I can use that bob url to save it.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040823/voice-recorder-saving-blob-file-to-server-c-sharp-mvc) is  the link that talks about saving blobs.
After that I am trynig to get it and download to server.

1- I get the link to blob file

```
var data = document.getElementById("save").href
```

After that 
I am using js code in my index.html file to send 
 blob url to php code.
JS code

```
<script>
function saveAudio(){
var req = null;
var url = "savefile.php";
var data = document.getElementById("save").href.toString();// document.getElementById("save").innerHTML;// = xhttp.responseText;;   // you have to check how to get the data from your saveAudio() method
window.alert(data);

(window.XMLHttpRequest) ? req = new XMLHttpRequest() : (window.ActiveXObject) ? req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : req = false; 
req.open("POST", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

if(data != null) //&& data != "")
{
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
  req.send(data);
}}


</script>
```

PHP code

```
<?php

$save_folder = dirname(__FILE__) ."/js";
if(! file_exists($save_folder)) {
    if(! mkdir($save_folder)) {
        die("failed to create save folder $save_folder");
    }
}

$key = 'filename';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["audiofile"]["tmp_name"];
$upload_name = $_FILES["audiofile"]["name"];
$type = $_FILES["audiofile"]["type"];
$filename = "$save_folder/$upload_name";
$saved = 0;
if(($type == 'audio/x-wav' || $type == 'application/octet-stream') && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.wav$/', $upload_name) ) {

    $saved = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filename) ? 1 : 0;
}

//name is needed to send in the php file

?>
```

I get 2 errors while compiling in browser
1-refused to set unsafe header "Content-length".
2-POST savefile.php 500

I suppose that there is something wrong with php file!

How canI handle these errors and accomplish uploading task?

  Is there any open source  which allows direct uploading blob-url to server without using php?
I appreciate any help and suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the line:
`req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);`

`XMLHttpRequest` isn't allowed to set these headers because that would be a security vulnerability. The `500` is most likely a result of the request failure.

You can read about `XMLHttpReqest` here http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method

Here are some other threads, same issue:

[Pass Blob through ajax to generate a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015555/pass-blob-through-ajax-to-generate-a-file)

[How can javascript upload a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob)