# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) sending blob to server C# MVC Web APi

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have been working for capturing audio from browser and send the files to IIS Server. Followed recorderjs article from Matt Diamond.  To upload the blob to server i got the reference from the link [Voice Recorder, Saving Blob file to server - C# , Mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040823/voice-recorder-saving-blob-file-to-server-c-sharp-mvc). But am getting error unsupported media type 415. It was mentioned to look for custom [MimeType("audio/wav")] attribute in the data model. But unable to find the solution . Two days am running for the solution. Would be great if someone help out.

By following the link am getting the error .(https://i.stack.imgur.com/chrx8.png)

```
   var fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('FileName', 'test.wav');
 fd.append('Recording', blob);

 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'application/json',
     url: 'http://localhost:53387/api/RecordingWav/Upload',
     data: fd,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false
 }).done(function (data) {
     console.log(data)
 });
```

My controller code look like

```
    public class RecordingWavController:ApiController{
[HttpPost]
public string Upload(Classmodel passage)
{
string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/UploadedFiles/{0}.wav", assage.FileName));
passage.Recording.SaveAs(path);
return 'success';
}
}
```

Model look like

```
    public class Classmodel
{
public string FileName { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase Recording { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance
regards.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369529/how-to-setup-a-webapi-controller-for-multipart-form-data

Comment: did you check if the IIS MIME list has "audio/wav"

Comment: Shyju . Thanks .  i have added  config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));  
 in webapiconfig. earlier issue is over. but model is getting null value. Any idea for that. What could be the issue.

Comment: Shrugo . Just checked thanks it has.